# Executing machine codes attached at the end of an executable

Tags: linux, object, gcc, linker, arm

I have a object file which has a main() function inside and just needs to be linked with crt... objects to be an executable . Unfortunately I can only compile and I can not link it to be an executable .

so I decided to create a c program ( on a pc with working GCC and linker ) to attach object(s) at the end of itself and execute the codes attached  at run time (simulating a linked object ).

I saw DL API but I do'nt know how to use it for the problem I said .

May sb help me to know , how I can executing a code attached at the end of an executable .

Comment: Explain why you cannot link your object file; it is incomprehensible.... If you can run `gcc` to compile (a `.c` source file into a `.o` object file), you should be able to run the *same* `gcc` to link that `.o` into an executable (otherwise, your `gcc` compiler chain is improperly installed)! The `*crt*.o` files are part of your toolchain!

Comment: And please, show or explain much more about your code. Do you have an URL to the source code and the building procedure? Publish your code as free software (e.g. on http://github.com/ or elsewhere) and show it!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid doing that; it would be a mess .... And it probably won't reliably work, at least if the program is dynamically linked to the  `libc6.so` (e.g. because of [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASLR))

Just use shared objects and dynamically linked libraries (See [dynamic linker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_linker) wikipage). You need to learn about [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html) etc.

If you really insist, take many weeks to learn a lot more: read Levine's book on [Linker and Loaders](http://www.iecc.com/linker/), read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), read many man pages (including [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), [elf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html), [ld.so(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html), ...) study the kernel code for `execve` and `mmap`, the GNU [libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org) source codes (for details about implementations of the dynamic linker), the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) or the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABI) for your target processor (is it an ARM?), learn more about the GNU [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/) etc, etc, etc.

<sup>In short, your life is too short doing such messy things, unless you are already an expert, e.g. able to implement your own dynamic  linker.</sup>

#### addenda

Apparently your real issue seems to use [tinycc](http://repo.or.cz/w/tinycc.git) on the ARM (under Android I am guessing). I would then ask on their mailing list (perhaps contribute with some patch), or simply use binutils and make your own GNU ld [linker script](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html) to make it work. Then the question becomes entirely different and completely unrelated to your original question. There might be some previous attempts to solve that, according to Google searches.

Comment: thanks for your helps. the reason I can not link is that I compiled tcc for arm . It can compile but can not link ( target operating system is android) so I decided to do the solution I said .

Comment: I compiled tcc on arm-linux-gnueabi , It completely works on gnueabi with no problems but while using it on arm-linux-androideabi ,compiling works but linking gives errors about crt*.o files. I tried to use gcc crt* files but It errors about libc_init and ...