# How to execute machine code appended to the end of an executable file using c++?

Tags: c++, append, executable, binaryfiles, machine-code

I have a program which appends machine code to the end of an executable, and I want to write a c++ program at the beginning of the executable to run the appended machine code.  The appended code will then run the original program.

My program will be running on a mac.

There is a similar question here: [Executing machine codes attached at the end of an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709783/executing-machine-codes-attached-at-the-end-of-an-executable)
However, the question was not answered, alternative solutions were given.  I cannot use linked lists, because the purpose of this program is to amend the functionality of executable files on machines which may not necessarily have a compiler installed.

Here is an example:

```
// C++ program at the beginning of file, runs appended machine code.

// Original program, must be skipped over and run after appended machine code is run.

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    FILE *input,*output;
    char buffer[512];

    =fopen("a.out","rb");
    output=fopen("filename","ab");

    for(;fread(buffer,512,1,input)==1;)
        fwrite(buffer,512,1,output);
    fclose(output);
    cout << "Testing, testing, testing" << endl;

    //Run original program
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Executing machine codes attached at the end of an executable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709783/executing-machine-codes-attached-at-the-end-of-an-executable)

Comment: This sounds way too much like writing a virus to me.

Comment: This smells like a classic XY problem. Why do you need to be able to do this?

Comment: @HoboSapiens The answer to that duplicate was not quite what I am looking for, they were discussing linked lists.

Comment: @MarkB I won't be creating  a virus, I just want to learn more about computer coding.  This particular problem has been bugging me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a program that creates an executable from the appended code and then executes it.
Or if what you want is that the executable executes code appended to it, then you would have to call that appended code as a function or jump to that in inline assembly ("call" or "jmp").